# How Do I Get SharePoint to recognize that a field type was changed on an InfoPath form?

Tags: infopath, forms-library

When I first designed and pulished my InfoPath form I mistakenly made two fields Text that should have been Whole Number.

I want to be able to sum these values on a SharePoint view, so I changed the InfoView template and changed the field types of those fields.  I then re-published and re-linked.  But SharePoint still thinks these fields are text and will not display the Sum option for totals.

Is there something I can do to correct this without having to wipe out the data or the library and start over?

Answer (score 4):

In InfoPath Designer, open the form template and go to File > Form Options > Property Promotion. Remove the field and publish the form. Then add the field to the promoted properties and publish the form again.

The view will show the column as empty, but the previously entered values still exist in the form. Just opening and closing the form will make the values appear.

The field will now be an integer and data can be summed.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using InfoPath Edit form or InfoPath Form (published as linked to Content Type, in a Forms Library) as they are behaving differently:

1. InfoPath Edit form - changing fields in either underlying list would
   require close and reopen the form - which would then ask to refresh.
   Or change the form and upon republishing would update the list.
2. InfoPath in either Content Type or Forms library would require
   either updating the actual content type and update Promoted fields,
       or updating Promoted fields and re-publishing would actuallly update
       the forms library.

To my sense you need to check few places:
In case 1. it could be that the TextBox via Properties must be
   changed with regards to the formatting to Number.
In case 2. the actual InfoPath would not update this small change in
   the form ONLY if field name also changes - practically re-create the
   field.

Answer (score 0):

When you do your sum formula in infopath, you could try something like:

number([field1])+number([field2])

the number function converts text to a number

Answer (score 0):

Unpromote the fields, this should remove them from the library. If not you will have to go to the site columns >> Microsoft InfoPath > and remove them columns there. Once they are removed you can promote them again with their new type.